# Why are my monitors not detected?

Tags: 15.04, display

I have 2 monitors connected, the laptop's builtin monitors and an external monitor, but my display settings screen shows nothing. Why? I can display my screen on both monitors but from the settings screen it looks like it is not working. What can I do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
sudo X -configure && sudo reboot now
```

Note : It will reboot your machine. Let me know.

Comment: This made my situation worse. Now the external monitor doesn't display the left menu and the graphics look b0rked. I can't believe this is happening with a modern os. And there is no way to rollback the update that caused this. Why not? MS-Windows has had rollback functionality for years. I should have stayed with Microsoft.

Comment: Patience... It happens some times. And trust me, driver problem in Windows are as worst as they can get. The menu is not displayed because the OS is treating one display as extension. Can be easily changed. Why dont you post a screenshot by editing your main post.

Comment: "Installing external displays to Ubuntu is easier than you might think. ."...yeah right! Now nothing is possible just because I want Ubuntu to work with HDMI output.

Comment: Agony will make it worst for you, not for me. I can help, but not really interested in listening you yammering....  And it works with HDMI, very easily. If you post screenshot, I can help.

Comment: You call it agony, I call it a worthless product wasting my time. I must spread the word that Ubuntu is not mature and the best way to do it is showing my attempts to achieve something that every other os can. I'm not even trying to accomplish something complicated. all I tried was an external monitor and then nothing is possible.

Comment: I Quit. May someone else not help you!